# Сравнение чисел Си

Tags: c, битовые-операции

Стоит задача: вернуть 1, если x < y, а иначе 0.
Использовать можно только битовые операции ( ! ~ & ^ | + << >> ), if использовать нельзя.

Программа не проходит все тесты, выдает неверный ответ. Помогите пожалуйста исправить.

```
int isLess(int x, int y)
{
    return ((x + ~y + ~1) >> 31) & 0x1;
}
```

Comment: Плюс можно, а минус нет? И еще - >> и << для знаковых, вообще говоря, насколько я помню - определяются реализацией..

Comment: Попробуйте разбить код на отдельны шаги с переменными и использовать дебаггер.

Comment: Да, минус нельзя(

Comment: У вас ошибка в вычислении отрицательного значения `y` через дополнительный код.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот такое монстрообразное родилось :)

```
(((x+~y+1)^((x^y)&((x+~y+1)^x)))>>31)&1;
```

Comment: Кто заминусовал - на чем не сработало, подскажите? Делал на VC++ 2017.

Comment: Все сработало, спасибо)

Comment: Только я не до конца понимаю, зачем делается битовое И

(x^y) &

Comment: Ну, кому-то же не понравилось, кто-то минус поставил :)

Comment: Проверка одинаковости знакового бита (потом же все смещается на 31 бит).

Comment: Поняла, спасибо